# Ubuntu 18 NFS Change

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, nfs

I'm trying to boot a custom linux kernel I built with Yocto on a raspberry pi using NFS for the root filesystem.

The thing is, the NFS server setup works perfectly in Ubuntu 14.04 and 16.04, but it does not work on 18.04. On 18.04 I always get:

```
VFS: Unable to mount root fs via NFS, trying floppy
```

AFAIK, all 3 setups are identical in terms of `/etc/export`

What gives? I know it's not the pi's fault since if I bring it over to an older computer it boots no problem. How can I troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently you have to force the pi to ask for NFSv3 otherwise the server defaults to NFSv4.  The fix is done on the pi itself in /boot/cmdline.txt.  Just append ",tcp,v3" to your nfsroot= parameter there.  So my nfsroot is defined as: `nfsroot=172.21.4.2:/mnt/pidata/piroot/r54,tcp,v3`

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please don't start your answer with"I have the same problem." This makes the reader think you are just saying "me too" and not providing a solution. Such non-answers are typically deleted by the moderators. +1 for a good answer otherwise.

Comment: I *think* this is the issue, still need to confirm!

Comment: Adding `v3` is enough for it to work; there is no need to force tcp.